# Battery always shows Estimating on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, power-management, indicator, battery, 19.04

Been using Ubuntu for over a year now had no issues, Since a few days my battery status is bit weird. It always shows me 100% and when I plugin charging it shows Estimating and it remains like this when I plug out the charger or plug in.

The following command shows the below result,

```
~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0   native-path:          (null)   power supply:         no   updated:     Do 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET (1561282273 seconds ago)   has history:    no   has statistics:       no   unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

The acpi -V , shows the below results,

```
~$ acpi -V
Battery 0: Discharging, 0%, 11:57:45 remaining
Adapter 0: off-line
Thermal 0: ok, 53.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 127.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode hot at temperature 127.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 1: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 2: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 4: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10



sudo tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = LENOVO 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = PABAS0241231
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Discharging
```

Any idea what is going on ?